# Вызов метода в дочернем элементе в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Есть следующая структура из элементов:

```
<App>
    <Header>
        <Switcher />
    </Header>
    <Content />
</App>
```

В классе `Content` описана функция `GetData`, которая производит запрос данных на сервере.
По событию в классе `Switcher` меняется состояние в классе `App`.

Каким образом можно произвести повторный вызов функции `GetData` по этому событию смены состояния в классе `App`?

Comment: А что используете? Redux? Hooks? или чистый React и классовые компоненты?

Comment: @Рустам Демонов, только react и классовые компоненты

Comment: Может refs использовать? https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Вообще в React принято передавать данные от родительских элементов к дочерним через пропсы. Возможно эта функция должна быть не у Content, а у кого-то из его предков.